# Reference Error: function is not defined - Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript that calls a function after a 1.5 second timer. In Chrome, it works great. In Firefox, I get a Reference Error: accessTransition is not defined. Any explanation for why this is the case?

```
$('#next-btn').click(function(e) {
    window.setTimeout(accessTransition, 1500);

    function accessTransition()
    {
        $('.fact-intro-1').slideUp(1000);
        $('.fact-text-1').css('display', 'inline-block');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why define the `accessTransition` function inside of the event handler?

Comment: Potentially a hoisting issue?

Comment: Crazy idea, but did you try moving the `setTimeout()` call to below where you're defining the function you're passing in to it? You're relying on Chrome to hoist that for you.

Comment: @Antiga thanks! that did the trick

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
function accessTransition()
    {
        $('.fact-intro-1').slideUp(1000);
        $('.fact-text-1').css('display', 'inline-block');
    }

$('#next-btn').click(function(e) {
    window.setTimeout(accessTransition, 1500);

}
```

I think timeout cannot get this function because it's nested in event handler function (javascript has function based scope).

Answer (score 1):

```
function accessTransition()
{
    $('.fact-intro-1').slideUp(1000);
    $('.fact-text-1').css('display', 'inline-block');
}

$('#next-btn').click(function(e) {
    window.setTimeout(accessTransition, 1500);
}
```

You should define the function outside the event handler.